# Perform a transformation on a single column in Apache beam

Tags: pipeline, apache-beam, dataflow

I have a CSV that I've loaded into Google Cloud Storage, and I am creating a Dataflow pipeline that will read and process the CSV, then perform a count of of listings by a single column.

How do I isolate the single column. Let's say the columns are id, city, sports_team. I want to count how many occurrences of a city show up.

My starting code is like so:

```
# Python's regular expression library
import re

# Beam and interactive Beam imports
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.runners.interactive.interactive_runner import InteractiveRunner
import apache_beam.runners.interactive.interactive_beam as ib

class SplitRecords(beam.DoFn):
    """Spilt the element into records, return rideable_type record."""
    def process(self, element):
        records = element.split(",")
        return [records[1]]

p = beam.Pipeline(InteractiveRunner())
lines = p | 'read in file' >> beam.io.ReadFromText("gs://ny-springml-data/AB_NYC_2019.csv", skip_header_lines=1)
records = lines | beam.ParDo(SplitRecords())
groups = (records | beam.Map(lambda x: (x, 1)) | beam.CombinePerKey(sum))
groups | beam.io.WriteToText('TEST2.txt')
```

I am getting an IndexError: list index out of range.... I'm extremely newb at all of this, so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably there's some unexpected line in your CVS file, e.g. a blank one. You could do something like

```
if len(records) < 2:
  raise ValueError("Bad line: %r" % element)
else:
  yield records[1]
```

to get a better error message.  I would also recommend looking into using [Beam Dataframes](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/dsls/dataframes/overview/) for this kind of task.